# Deciding between unique, primary, or increments in Laravel Migrations

Tags: sqlite, laravel, migration, eloquent

I have a table of of data where the primary unique element is called a `CRN`, which denotes "course registration number", and it's an integer value.

In this table there are around 4000 classes, and each class has a unique CRN.

My question is, in my schema builder for migrations, should this I set the `CRN` as a unique, a primary, or an increments?

According to my usage, a unique makes the most sense.

The CRN is indeed unique, and never changes. I have a script that updates the other columns that corresponds to this CRN, and having CRN as unique will prevent additional rows of the same CRN created.

A bug I ran into without setting any of these constraints of unique/primary/increments is, when I re-ran my script that updates the enrollment numbers, for example, for a CRN, a new row is generated instead of it being updated. So now I have two rows of data of the same CRN.

Comment: İf your key, CRN, is surrogate key then yo have to make it unique ,primary and increment beacuse it is surrogate key and has no meaning with your object.If it is natural key then you dont have to just make it unique

Comment: Are you able to make one column all those three properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İf your key, CRN, is surrogate key then you should make it unique ,primary and increment beacuse it is surrogate key and has no meaning with your object.If it is natural key then you dont have to make it incremented just make it unique.

If it is surrogate then create it with `$table->increments('id'`) and this will make it primary,unique and incremented.If it is natural key

```
$table->string('crn')->unique();
$table->primary('crn');
```

And i think your `'crn'` seems natural key.

Comment: Would it auto-increment? A `CRN` *has* to be the value I assign it, and it cannot be anything else.

Comment: then your CRN is natural key ,you just need to make it unique and primary