# Laravel 5.5 Schema auto increment with prefix and suffix

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm looking on a way to add a auto increment column to my table that consist on a unique job number format **(2 digit year + 3 digit auto increment + 1 digit letter)** eg in 2017 we had company "B" > *17632b, 17633b, 17634b* ... while company "C" *17500c, 17501c...* now in 2018 > *18001b, 18002b, 18001c, etc ...*

Is there a straight way using `$table->increments('id');` on my migration schema or I'll have to have a custom approach? Closest answer I found was [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792915/deciding-between-unique-primary-or-increments-in-laravel-migrations)

```
public static function getNextSeriesFor($category)
{
    $number = false;
    $details = \App\Series::where('category', $category)->first();
    if ($details != null) {
        $series_number = $details->series_number;
        $details->series_number = $details->series_number + 1;
        $details->save();
        $number = $details->prefix.$series_number;
    }

    return $number;
}
```

But as I'm just a beginner in laravel, I'm not sure how to implement this solution to my needs.

Comment: This is really a MySQL problem AFAIK, and MySQL does not support the type of auto increment you havd in mind.

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen I was afraid so, is anyone came across a solution in Laravel and care to share? Thanks

Comment: One way is to not use auto increment and create `id` value yourself each time you insert into the table.